# Django comments (threadedcomments) и одинаковые комментарии

Tags: комментарии, django

Здравствуйте!

Вот заметил такую особенность: я не могу дважды создать одинаковый комментарий для одного объекта.

Используется приложение [threadedcomments](https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments), слегка допиленное мной (емейл не обязателен и по мелочи всякое. ничего глобального.) Возможно, кто-то его знает.

Очень хочется понять, почему это происходит. В стандартной админке все проходит без проблем. Это ошибка в моем коде? Или в коде threadedcomments? Или это такая фича? Почему-то нигде в документации я не нашел ни слова об этом.

И вот что еще странно: я полез по всем модулям, которые участвуют в сохранении (начиная от django.contrib.comments.urls) расставляя отладочные принты в поисках того места, где блокируется сохранение. На модуле django.db.models.base я сдался. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, дело в [самой django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/forms.py#L147) (вызывается этот метод чуть выше) - а Ваша форма наследуется от "родной".

Comment: Ишь ты хитрые какие... А как же явное лучне неявного и все такое? Ладно, хрен бы с ним. Спасибо.

Comment: Справедливости ради, contrib.comments один из самых дурацки сделанных и редко используемых contrib apps. Написать свои комментарии "как надо" часто проще, чем юзать джанговские.